# aws-amplify has Auth null in S3 hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using aws-amplify for my frontend to handle all things authentications for my users, and it's working great in my local environment. The problem that I'm getting is when I tried to upload my code to a public S3 static hosted website. Everything else is working fine, but whenever I tried to access Amplify.Auth is breaking.

Here is my configuration:

```js
      Amplify.configure({
        Auth: {
          region: "us-west-2",
          userPoolId: "us-west-2-MY-POOL-ID",
          userPoolWebClientId: "MyUserPoolWebClientID",
        },
      }); // this runs without any errors
```

And here is where it breaks in S3 (`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'signIn'`)
:

```js
  public async login(credentials: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
  }): Promise<CognitoUser> {
    return await Amplify.Auth.signIn({ // Auth is defined in localhost, but not it S3
      username: credentials.email,
      password: credentials.password,
    });
  }
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm trying to look up if I need some sort of policy to give access to my S3 bucket to use cognito, but I haven't been able to find anything. What am I missing?